# jQuery Mobile Transitions Not Working At All

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I simply can't get the jQuery Mobile Transitions (I only want the "slide" one!) to happen but it's all a no-go. It just loads the page normally each time.

Full HTML code here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Parent Guide</title>

        <script>
        //iScroll initiate
            var myScroll;
            function loaded() {
                myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
            }
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
        </script> 

    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" id="header"><h1>The Parent Guide</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content" id="wrapper">
                <div id="scroller">
                    <div id="content">
                        <a href="grid/1.html">Link</a>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer"><a href="about.html"><div class="footer_abt"></div></a></div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - but I'm using Phonegap to develop for mobile but it's not working in browser. I link to both jQuery and jQuery Mobile in the header.

Comment: Android, iOS, WM or Blackberry? Version? Or in your case browser Firefoc/Chrome..?

Comment: iOS for mobile, v5.1+, and the latest version of Chrome. The page demos on the jQuery Mobile Docs website work fine.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is change jquery-1.9.0.min.js with jquery-1.8.2.min.js. jQM 1.2 was built to work with jQ 1.8.2.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much - it's working perfectly. Now just gotta mess around with the screwed-up css changes! Give this as an answer and I'll tick it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change jquery-1.9.0.min.js with a jquery-1.8.2.min.js version and that is that.